# Defining a Polymorphic Relationship in Laravel with Databases on Different Servers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project where I have two databases residing on different servers. I'm trying to establish a polymorphic relationship between models where the tables involved are in these separate databases.

I am making use of Spatie's permission package and their Multitenancy package but the examples below are simplified.

The database structure is:

```yaml
# Landlord Connection
roles
    id - integer
    name - string

# Tenant Connection
users
    id - integer
    name - string

# Tenant Connection
model_has_roles
    role_id - integer
    model_id - integer
    model_type - string
```

The models are:

```php
class Role
{
    protected $connection = 'tenant';
    
    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(
            related: Role::class,
            name: 'model',
            table: 'model_has_roles',
            foreignPivotKey: 'model_id',
            relatedPivotKey: 'role_id'
        );
    }
}

class User
{
    protected $connection = 'landlord';
    
    public function roles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        $databaseName = Tenant::current()->getDatabaseName();
    
        return $this->morphToMany(
            related: Role::class,
            name: 'model',
            table: "{$databaseName}.model_has_roles",
            foreignPivotKey: 'model_id',
            relatedPivotKey: 'role_id'
        );
    }
}
```

The database configuration is:

```php
return [
    'connections' => [
        'tenant' => [
            'driver'   => 'mysql',
            'host'     => '192.168.1.1',
            'database' => 'landlord',
            ...
        ],
        
        'landlord' => [
            'driver'   => 'mysql',
            'host'     => '192.168.1.2',
            'database' => 'tenant',
            ...
        ],
    ],
];
```

This works fine when both connections are on the same server. However, the following error occurs when the databases are on different servers:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1049 Unknown database 'tenant_database_name' (Connection: landlord, SQL: select `roles`.*, `tenant_database_name`.`model_has_roles`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `tenant_database_name`.`model_has_roles`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `tenant_database_name`.`model_has_roles`.`model_type` as `pivot_model_type` from `roles` inner join `tenant_database_name`.`model_has_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `tenant_database_name`.`model_has_roles`.`role_id` where `tenant_database_name`.`model_has_roles`.`model_id` = 1 and `tenant_database_name`.`model_has_roles`.`model_type` = App\User)
```

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of relying on Eloquent's relationship methods, you might need to use manual queries (using the DB facade) to fetch related data. This would involve writing custom join statements and handling the relationships in your application logic. If feasible, consider replicating the necessary data from one database to another. This approach has its own set of challenges, such as keeping the data synchronized. Another approach could be to set up an API layer for each database/server. Your Laravel application could interact with these APIs to fetch and synchronize data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Role
{
    protected $connection = 'tenant';
    
    public function roles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(
            related: Role::class,
            name: 'model',
            table: 'tenant.model_has_roles', // Explicitly specify the table name
            foreignPivotKey: 'model_id',
            relatedPivotKey: 'role_id'
        );
    }
}

class User
{
    protected $connection = 'landlord';
    
    public function roles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        $databaseName = Tenant::current()->getDatabaseName();
    
        return $this->morphToMany(
            related: Role::class,
            name: 'model',
            table: "{$databaseName}.model_has_roles",
            foreignPivotKey: 'model_id',
            relatedPivotKey: 'role_id'
        );
    }
}
```